# How to get the name assign to the serial port dynamically on which RFID reader connected

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, port, rfid

I am trying to read the data from RFID reader and store the data in the log file through Raspberry Pi.

But sometimes an error occurs dev/ttyUSB0 not found and when I check the name assign to the port using "dmesg | grep tty" command the names change to "ttyUSB1 or ttyUSB2" so I need to change the code each time.

Is there any solution for This??

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change default names for USB virtual serial ports in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673043/change-default-names-for-usb-virtual-serial-ports-in-linux)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/49910/118098

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code like this one to know what device is attached to what port:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import subprocess, os

def getUSBName(devSerial):
   if(os.path.exists(devSerial)==False):
       return "No USB"
   dataAttributes = subprocess.Popen("udevadm info --name=" + devSerial + " --attribute-walk", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read().decode('utf-8').split('\n')

    for at in dataAttributes:
        if(at.find("busnum")!=-1):
            bus = at.replace(" ", "")[-2].zfill(3)
            #print("bus = " + bus);
            break

    for at in dataAttributes:
        if(at.find("devnum")!=-1):
            device = at.replace(" ", "")[-2].zfill(3)
            #print("device = " + device)
            break

    dataUSB = subprocess.Popen("lsusb", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read().decode('utf-8').split('\n')

    searchline = "Bus " + bus + " Device " + device + ":"

    for usb in dataUSB:
        if usb.find(searchline)!=-1:
            return usb



devSerial = "/dev/ttyUSB0"

print(getUSBName(devSerial))
```

Then you can scan some ports (/dev/ttyUSB0, /dev/ttyUSB1, /dev/ttyUSB2...) and search with a keyword your device.